# Corda - problem using VaultCustomQueryCriteria

Tags: blockchain, corda

I'm trying to use a VaultCustomQueryCriteria (*Corda - Java*) with the aggregate function **SUM**, but I get no results.

If I use another VaultCustomQueryCriteria, the query works.

What am I doing wrong?

Below some examples:

**Query OK:**

```
QueryCriteria statusCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED);

Field name = ExampleSchemaV1.Ingestion.class.getDeclaredField("name");

QueryCriteria countCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(Builder.equal(name, "Mark"));
List<StateAndRef<IngestionState>> results = rpcOps.vaultQueryByCriteria(countCriteria,IngestionState.class).getStates();
```

**Query KO:** (no results)

```
QueryCriteria statusCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED);

Field nr = ExampleSchemaV1.Ingestion.class.getDeclaredField("nr");    
Field name = ExampleSchemaV1.Ingestion.class.getDeclaredField("name");

CriteriaExpression sumQta = Builder.sum(nr, Arrays.asList(name));    
QueryCriteria sumQtaCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(sumQta);

QueryCriteria criteria = statusCriteria.and(sumQtaCriteria);

List<StateAndRef<IngestionState>> results = rpcOps.vaultQueryByCriteria(criteria,IngestionState.class).getStates();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each vault query returns a `Vault.Page` object. When performing a sum query, the result of the sum is accessible via `Vault.Page.getOtherResults()`, rather than via `Vault.Page.getStates()`.

This is because the sum query doesn't return any actual states, but rather the result of a computation over these states.